# Wordpress site blank - changing theme and disabling plugins do not work

Tags: wordpress

I originally did a long one page layout that used front-page.php which fetched content from multiple pages. Plugins used ACF, ACF Flexible Content and ACF Repeater. Works like a charm at but now i need to add blog into it. I’m usin Bootstrap 3 so i started to merge _tk into my current theme.

I installed new WP on a different server, installed plugins and imported XML. After an hour of hacking the site goes blank.

WP-Admin stays accessible. Tried disabling all plugins and changing to original theme or Twenty Twelwe do not help. Still blank page.

Tried enabling error reporting with:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Blank page.

Increased memory limit to 128M, no help.

WP-Admin stays accessible all time.

Dropping all tables, deleting all files with FTP, re-installing, adding plugins, importing XML makes the site to work perfectly again. Until ~one hour of hacking, site goes blank again.

What to do?

edit:

here's my old functions.php which is really simple.

```
<?php
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
?>
```

here's my old header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?> ">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/_config.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/fonts.css">


        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/vendor/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/vendor/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link href="apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes='144x144'/> 
        <link href="apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes='72x72'/> 
        <link href="apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes='114x114'/> 
        <link href="apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes='57x57'/>
        <meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png"/> 
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png"> 
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#f87242"/> 
        <meta name="application-name" content="Scoutzie.com" />

        <?php  wp_head(); ?>

    </head>
    <body>
```

Comment: Stop "hacking"...But seriously, what do you call "hacking"?

Comment: Merging _tk theme and my earlier theme.  For example combining functions.php files by trial &  error. My PHP skills are close to nonexistent.

Comment: I see, when you aren't sure about something you should ask here. If you want paste the code from your functions.php theme go ahead. Just to be sure, where did you put the `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`?

Comment: i added functions.php and header.php to the original question. i put it to wp-config.php and i get notifications on admin side.

Comment: @user2795613 Are you able to provide URL of the site?

Comment: Yes, certainly http://testiserveri.fi/config2/. I re-installed the site and have not yet have had time to continue working on it – it's still working ok.